# htaccess - How to NOT send Access Control headers when same origin

Tags: .htaccess, cors

My API caters to requests from other origins, so I have set the following in `.htaccess`:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type,Accept"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Type,Content-Length"
```

However, I would like for these headers to NOT show up when there is no preflight required, e.g., for `GET` requests, or when my own site is accessing this API.

An example:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1/api/featured/ -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2016 08:33:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 OpenSSL/1.0.1k-fips PHP/5.6.19
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type,Content-Length
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.19
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

This feels rather extraneous; this is a curl in localhost, and it's still sending the CORS headers. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppressing the CORS headers when the request is same-origin can be done with something like:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^https://example\.com$" IS_SAME_ORIGIN
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=!IS_SAME_ORIGIN
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type,Accept" env=!IS_SAME_ORIGIN
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" env=!IS_SAME_ORIGIN
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Type,Content-Length" env=!IS_SAME_ORIGIN
```

The [SetEnvIf](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) makes Apache check the `Origin` request header and set an `IS_SAME_ORIGIN` [environment variable](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html) if the value of the `Origin` header is "`https://example.com`".

The other lines use the [optional final argument of the Header directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#Header) to specify that the CORS headers are sent only if the `IS_SAME_ORIGIN` environment variable is **not** set.

Comment: It works! :D For curl, I had to add `-H "<domain>"`, but it seems browsers send the Origin header automatically. Thanks!